# azure:storage:storage_exception m_http_status_code = 0 when using invalid credentials

Tags: c++, azure

In the following c++ code snippet a storage_exception is thrown when invalid credentials are used to create the cloud_storage_account object which is expected, what's not expected is that the caught storage exception doesn't contain any useful information (http_status_code = 0).

What is the expected result in this situation (http status of 0 or 403)?
I haven't found in the documentation what's to be expected here.

```
    try {
    azure::storage::storage_credentials storageCredentials
        = azure::storage::storage_credentials(azureAccountName, azureAccountKey);

    azure::storage::cloud_storage_account storageAccount
        = azure::storage::cloud_storage_account(storageCredentials, useHTTPS);

    if (true == storageAccount.is_initialized()) {
        blobClient = storageAccount.create_cloud_blob_client();

        azure::storage::cloud_blob_container blobContainer = blobClient.get_container_reference(L"ContainerName");

        blobContainer.exists();
    }
}
catch (azure::storage::storage_exception & storageException) {
    web::http::status_code statusCode = storageException.result().http_status_code();
}
```

Output in VS debugger:
[No http status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPGCx.png)

Comment: Do you know on which line of code you're getting an exception? Also, please share what account key you're using.

Comment: The exception is thrown when checking if the container exists (blobContainer.exists();). In the snippet provided the account key is valid but I'm using an invalid account name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this as Microsoft have finally replied to my question [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp/issues/319).

1. If a nonexistent storage account is provided, then the endpoint is
   invalid and DNS record cannot be found. What will happen is up to
   the underlying HTTP client, usually timeout. The HTTP status code in
   exception would be undefined, since the HTTP connection isn't
   established at all.
2. If the shared key is not a valid base64-encoded string,
   std::runtime_error will be thrown.
3. If the shared key is a valid base64-encoded string but the key is
   incorrect (e.g. revoked), HTTP status code 403 will be returned.
4. Network issue, this is pretty much the same as case 1.